# how do i render only when value gets updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a beginner to react and I am creating a to do list as my first project. Here I am using 2 different component and using use states as an array. And when I try to update the item to the array it causes too many re-renders. I can do it in a single component but I want to try it in multiple components to learn more.

```
import React, { useState} from "react";

interface Props {
  item: string;
}

const TaskList = ({ item}: Props) => {
  const [taskListItem, taskListItemAdd] = useState<string[]>([]);
  taskListItemAdd((taskListItem) => [...taskListItem, item])
  return (
    <>
      <ul className="list-group">
        {taskListItem.map((item, num) => {
          console.log(num , item);
          return (
            <li className="list-group-item " key={num}>
              <button className="btn btn-primary">
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  className="bi bi-check"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                >
                  <path d="M10.97 4.97a.75.75 0 0 1 1.07 1.05l-3.99 4.99a.75.75 0 0 1-1.08.02L4.324 8.384a.75.75 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.094 2.093 3.473-4.425a.267.267 0 0 1 .02-.022z" />
                </svg>
              </button>
              {item}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default TaskList;
```

`taskListItemAdd((taskListItem) => [...taskListItem, item])`
This is the line that is causing Re-Render and I am confused in what step to take inorder to solve this re-render so that everytime when item gets updated, then only it renders

Comment: thats fine in this case its Isolated component so only his childrens will rerender, also everytime you change your STATE current component and his children will rerender unless you use ``useMemo`` hook to cache component and prevent rerenders

btw in some cases you can use ``useRef`` with ``forwardRef`` and ``useImperativeHandle`` insted of ``useState`` to avoid rerenders in inputs when you type

but if you want see changes in UI you need rerender